# C++ and coverity issues

Tags: c++, coding-style, static-analysis, coverity-prevent, function-signature

```
MyClass* const Func(const std::string& statename)
```

for this coverity is giving the error

> Parse warning (PW.USELESS_TYPE_QUALIFIER_ON_RETURN_TYPE) type
>   qualifier on return type is meaningless .

Do we really need to remove the const here.?

Answer (score 6):

The warning is correct. The `MyClass* const` is not needed. It should be `MyClass*` simply. However, you don't need to remove it, but you should remove it.

The reason is, *theoretically* `MyClass* const` would prevent the return value of `Func()` from being edited. But that is anyway not editable even without `const`, as it's **not an lvalue**.See the [demo](http://ideone.com/az11u) here. So with/without `const`, the compiler will always generate error, for an attempt to modify the return value of `Func()`.

Comment: Thanks for the nice explanation. Does the same applies the following as well ? here also I ma getting the coverity warning.static char const * const GetInstanceName( InstanceId Id ) ;

inline const GraphicClass *const GetLogo() const;

Comment: static char const * const GetInstanceName( InstanceId Id ) ;

inline const GraphicClass *const GetLogo() const;

Comment: @Sudhakar, yes. Return type pointer is not an lvalue, so compiler will take care of making it unassignable. You don't need to make it `const`.

Comment: Thank you. this info was helpful.

Comment: One thing I'd add to the answer: Be careful that "MyClass* const" wasn't supposed to be "const MyClass*". If the const comes before the '*' then it IS meaningful, and maybe what the original programmer meant.

Answer (score 5):

The `const` in the return type (`MyClass* const`) is indeed completely pointless. At the same time, it does no harm other than making the code more verbose. I personally would remove it.

To understand why it's pointless, consider the following:

```
MyClass* p = Func(statement);
```

What difference did the `const` make?

In other words, returning `T* const` is conceptually no different to returning `const int`.

Comment: any commnets on the following ? Does the same applies the following as well ? here also I am getting the coverity warning.        static char const * const GetInstanceName( InstanceId Id ) ;  inline const GraphicClass *const GetLogo() const;

Comment: @Sudhakar: It does. In each of the declarations, one of the `consts` is pointless.

Comment: Thank you. this info was helpful.

Answer (score 3):

You don't *need* to remove the `const` to get working code, but the code would most certainly be better without the pointless `const`. That's what the "warning" word in front of the "error" says, too.

Comment: I understand that. Is the const here really not needed ? I think that it returns a unmodifiable pointer to a class. (i.e) we can not change the pointer. but we can change the contents

Comment: And what do you do with that pointer that's returned?  You assign it to some variable.  It's the type of _that_ variable that matters.